# Post MQ Message CorrelationID As A String Not Bytes C#

Tags: c#, ibm-mq, mq

I am using the IBM.WMQ (amqmdnet dll). On the MQMessage object it has a property to set the correlationID in byte[].

```
  IBM.WMQ.MQMessage msg = new IBM.WMQ.MQMessage();
  msg.Write(sendBuffer);


  //THIS IS byte[]
  msg.CorrelationId = MQUtils.StringToCorrelationId(corrId);
```

I want to set the correlaitonID as a string. Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: msg.CorrelationId accepts byte[], so if i use ToString() it will not compile

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(corrID.ToCharArray(), 0, msg.CorrelationId, 0, corrID.Length);
```

Comment: This code sets msg.CorrelationId? I dont see a msg.CorrelationId =

Comment: Seriously?  Look at the 3rd parameter.